# Clean URLs and php extension on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, clean-urls, nginx-location

I've looked at dozens of other questions and references on the web - and by all my calculations, my setup should work, but it doesn't.

I have nginx installation with php-fpm.  If I try to access a .php file, it runs correctly and I get the correct results.  I got this in my config file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Now, I want to setup my web app so that `/somedir/file` automatically executes `/somdir/file.php` while still displaying `/somdir/file` in the browser's address bar.  So I modified my config to contain the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?query_string
}
```

This *kind of* works, that is, the server does access the .php file.  Yet, instead of executing it using the existing `location ~ \.php$` block above, it simply spits the php source code as the download into the browser.  If I append the .php manually to the requested URL, then the php is executed.

It feels as if once the server matches `try_files` to `$uri.php`, it then does not do another pass at locations to see that what it needs to do with the php files.  I tried putting the php block above and below the `location /`, but it makes no difference.

How can I get the php to be executed?

Comment: Well, it should work. Show full server block

Comment: You are missing a trailing `;`. Is that just a typo in the question?

Answer (score -1):

You want `file.php` to be treated as an index file, so that `domain.com/dir/file.php` works on `domain.com/dir/` ?

Why not just rename it to index.php?

You can do this by adding this param on your location block:

```
index              index.html file.php index.php;
```

If not, you might want to look into writing a rewrite rule for nginx to map `domain.com/dir/` to `domain.com/dir/file.php` (but you have to do it for each dir that you need it to work)